# Add XPath parameter dynamically in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Is it possible in Selenium to add an XPath parameter dynamically?

I have following code:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='boxes']")
public List<WebElement> boxes;

String randomString = "something";
String startLocator = "//div[@class='cardLabel'][contains(text(), '";
String endLocator = "')]";
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(startLocator+randomString+endLocator)));
```

Is it possible to use `boxes` locator somehow and append text parameter?

Comment: You cannot use @FindBy with a variable, but you can use variables in xpaths in other scenarios.  There are several methods, but I like to use replace() and start with a replaceable parameter in the xpath, something like //tr[@account='%AcctNo%'] and then replace %AcctNo% with the actual account number in a loop, for example.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer, no

`@FindBy` is an annotation in Java, and as such, it happens BEFORE the code is run. So well before you reach the webpage, `@FindBy` has finalized.

### Long answer, no, but you can come close

You can however build xpath (and css) via String variables. They just need to be `final` so they can never change.

```
private final String xModal = "//div[@class='content']/div[@class='modal']";
private final String xModalHeader = "/div[@class='modal-header']";
private final String xModalBody = "/div[@class='modal-body']";
private final String xModalFooter = "/div[@class='modal-footer']";

@FindBy(xpath = xModal + xModalFooter + "/a[@class='btn-cancel']";
private WebElement searchModalCancel;

@FindBy(xpath = xModal + xModalFooter + "/a[@class='btn-submit']";
private WebElement searchModalSubmit;
```

It's very useful when dealing with a lot of similar elements.

In your case:

```
String final randomString = "something";
String final startLocator = "//div[@class='cardLabel'][contains(text(), '";
String final endLocator = "')]";
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(startLocator + randomString + endLocator)));
```

would work.

In your example, you actually aren't using `boxes` at all. You would need some sort if iteration to loop through each box and wait for it to be clickable.